# Como colocar valor de id contido no input em outro lugar da página com javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Gostaria de saber como posso pegar um dado contido em um id dentro de um input e colocar em outro lugar da página com ajuda do javascript como segue no exemplo abaixo:

HTML:

```html
<!-- Dado ID -->
<input name='dt_situacao' id='dt_situacao' type='hidden'>

<!-- Dado ID A Ser Inserido-->
<table class="table table-responsive" border="0">
<tr>
<th>Situação inicial:</th>
<td>id_situacao</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Podes fazer isso no servidor... isso é uma opção?

Comment: @Sergio, ele está aprendendo, vai devagar.

Comment: @AugustoVasques exato, por isso é bom aprender as coisas de maneira certa do princípio :)

Comment: De fato. Pesquisei aqui o termo. Rsrsrsrsrs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se eu entendi:
  Pra pegar um valor de um id você usa `document.getElementById`, exemplo de utilização:

```
var caixa = document.getElementById("divcaixa");
   caixa.style.display = "none";
```

Pra pegar valor de um input faz o seguinte:

```
 var teste = document.getElementeById("dt_situação").value;
    var x = document.getElementById("id do lugar que quer colorcar");
    x.innerHTML = teste;
```

Não testei, mas creio que ta certo, se tiver errado é alguma sintax, mas a logica e os comando estão certo.

Comment: Muito obrigado. Era exatamente dessa lógica "x.innerHTML = teste;" que estava atrás.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar a função querySelector para localizar os elementos no DOM e a função innerText/innerHTML para atualizar o conteúdo de um elemento.

Pelo que eu entendi, o seu problema seria resolvido da seguinte forma:

```
var input = document.querySelector('#dt_situacao') //Localizando o input no DOM
var td_situacao = document.querySelector('td') //Recomendo você atribuir um ID ou uma classe nesse elemento para não precisar fazer uma busca pelo nome da TAG.

// Adicionando evento para quando for digitado algo no input, atualizar o TD.
input.addEventListener('keypress', function($event){
    td_situacao.innerText = $event.target.value
})
```

Você também pode encurtar a função utilizando ES6. Segue o exemplo:

```
input.addEventListener('keypress', ({target: {value}}) => td_situacao.innerText = value)
```